# Multiple controller in one module in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework2

hi i am new in zend framework2.2.0. i want to create one module with multiple controller i have download "Album" module from github and its working fine
Now i want to add the more controller in it
the below i have shown my folder structure for file in module

```
module/
    Album/
         config/
             module.config.php
         src/
            Album/
                Controller/
                         AlbumController.php
                         UserController.php
               Form/
                     AlbumForm.php
                     UserForm.php
               Model/
                   AlbumTable.php 
                   Album.php
                   UserTable.php 
                   User.php

        view/
            album/ 
                 album/             
                       index.phtml
                 user/             
                       index.phtml
```

i have also changed all the name space in file

namespace Album\Controller;

class UserController extends \Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController

and some indexAction method witch returns a new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();

then you can create your viewfile in

Album/view/Album/user/index.phtml 
i did above changes.
is there any chage needed in "Album/Module.php" file ?
can you tell me through which link i can see users list ?

i and tired with this error help me to get out of it

[image]

Comment: Which error ? I don't see any error message hint in your question.

Comment: if it successfull so through which link i can see the users list ?  "/album/user" or directly "/user" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may need to add url rules for user in module.config.php in Album/config folder. Then you can access the url like

```
// The following section is new and should be added to your file
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'user' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/user[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\User',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Also

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
        'Album\Controller\User' => 'Album\Controller\UserController',
    ),
),
```

Comment: i did the same thing in same file but still get the same error message

Comment: i am using "project/public/user". Now i am getting this error "Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Album\Model\UserTable"

Comment: You may need to add similar code for user in getServiceConfig method of Module.php like existing albumtable code

Comment: finally i did it. we have to assign the database table to user. so need to chage the "Album/Module.php" file. i got the list of all the user

Comment: can you tell me now how i access the album function in user controller ?

Comment: By using $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Album\Model\UserTable')->someUserMethod();

Comment: i write this in my album controller "$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Album\Model\UserTable')->indexAction();"  and i get this error message "Call to undefined method Message\Model\UserTable::indexAction() "  i have also included "use Message\Model\user;" in album controller in top

Comment: Well you can't call methods of another controller in this way. It is only way to call method from models. like $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Album\Model\UserTable')->getUserList(); OR $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Album\Model\UserTable')->addUser();.

Comment: hey i am getting the error with the $this->url. i cant pass more than one parameter in the link. right now i am passing '<a href="<?php echo $this->url('message',array('action'=>'delete', 'id' => $message->message_id, 'aa' => 23));?>"> but when i hover it show only id not aa'

Comment: @deckjohn One suggestion please post this problem as seperate question as more people can help you in this regard.

Comment: if anyone can help me on my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954383/a-link-pass-multiple-parameter-in-zend-framework