# a link pass multiple parameter in zend framework

Tags: forms, url, zend-framework2

hi i am new in zend framework 2.2.0. i want to create the a link that go to delete page right now i am passing only id in the url so i want to pass another id in it.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('message',array('action'=>'delete', 'id' => $message->message_id));?>">Add to Trash</a>
```

right now in this link message id is passing i also  want to pass one more id named "did" in this link

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('message',array('action'=>'delete', 'id' => $message->message_id,'did'=>$message->deliver_id));?>">Add to Trash</a>
```

how can i get this ?
thanks in advance

Comment: See SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785190/how-can-you-add-query-parameters-in-the-zf2-url-view-helper

Answer (score 1):

You should use url view helper's third argument ($options) to pass your variables in the query string. Example:

```
$route = 'message';
$param = array('action' => 'delete');
$opts  = array(
           'query' => array(
              'id'  => $message->message_id,
              'did' => $message->deliver_id
              )
           );

$this->url($route, $params, $opts);
```

Comment: I'd suggest this method, too. But it depends on what the URL should look like and how the developer wants to access the params (either via fromRoute() or fromPost()).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "did" to your message route like this:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'message' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/:action/:id[/:did]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    'did'    => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),

echo $this->url('message',array('action'=>'delete', 'id' => $message->message_id,'did'=>$message->deliver_id);
// output: /delete/1/2
```